# Dynamic Switching of WiFi using a shell program in Raspberry Pi / Ubuntu / Debian

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, debian, raspberry-pi

How can I check in a shell script, whether the system is connected to WiFi-1 and if not connected, connect to WiFi-2? I tried using wpa_supplicant and interfaces configurations, but not working as expected. I followed this [tutorial](http://natisbad.org/dyn-net/index.html)

If there is any other way of doing this, please let me know.

/etc/network/interfaces file

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet6 manual
    pre-up ip link set dev eth0 up || true
    wpa-iface eth0
    wpa-driver wired
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant_wired.conf
    pre-down /etc/netplug/netplug eth0 out >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
    post-down ip link set dev eth0 down || true

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
      pre-up ip link set dev wlan0 up || true
      wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
      wpa-driver wext
      pre-down /etc/netplug/netplug wlan0 out >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
      post-down ip link set dev wlan0 down || true

# open is specific (IPv6 only) so I just stop dhcp via netplug
iface open inet manual
      up   /etc/netplug/netplug wlan0 out >/dev/null 2>&1 || true

iface default inet manual
      up   /etc/netplug/netplug wlan0 in  >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
      down /etc/netplug/netplug wlan0 out >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have already found the solution by now. Anyway as a workaround to do this you can install Network manager (supports all debian distributions including ubuntu/raspbian/etc)

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager
```

And then add required network configuration to `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` folder.
Sample configuration for a wifi network connection as follows:

```js
[connection]
id=milanWiFi
uuid=56439211-1067-4334-b199-b73ceed32d83
type=802-11-wireless

[802-11-wireless]
ssid=milanWiFi
mode=infrastructure
mac-address=84:3A:4B:9B:CF:66
security=802-11-wireless-security

[802-11-wireless-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
auth-alg=open
psk=milan123

[ipv4]
method=auto

[ipv6]
method=auto
```

Here, `id` is an unique name for your connection and you can obtain `uuid` by calling,
`uuidgen` command in the console.
For you to get the available wifi connections, you can use

```
sudo iw dev wlan0 scan
```

and there you can see the relevant details about the connections. What you have to do is to grab the details out of it and create the configuration file.